# How do i use the switch response on mapped response when the value is different?

Tags: c#

I have been trying to  Use a switch statement on the mapped response to determine which day of the week it is. Based on the response, write a string to the user. For example, for Monday, write .Monday is the first weekday.. For Tuesday, write .Tuesday is the second weekday,. and so on.

i  have tried as mentioned below and C# doesn't allow to use OR || operator either can someone help me out?

```
using System;

enum WeekDay { Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday };

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What day is today");
        String strday = Console.ReadLine();

        WeekDay Result = WeekDay.Sunday;
        WeekDay Result1 = WeekDay.Monday;
        WeekDay Result2 = WeekDay.Tuesday;

        switch (Result)
        {
            case WeekDay.Sunday:
            Console.WriteLine("Sunday is a first day");
            break;
        }

        switch (Result1)
        {
            case WeekDay.Monday:
            Console.WriteLine("Monday is a second day");
            break;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's because the syntax of your switch is a little off.  You're 100% correct that switch doesn't allow && or || operations.  I think you would want something like this:

```
DateTime curDate = DateTime.Now;

    switch(curDate.DayofWeek) //day of week is an enum, you can .ToString() it to compare against "Monday", "Tuesday", etc... or leave it as an INT, your call. 
    {
       case (1):
          Console.WriteLine("Sunday is first day")
          break;
       case (2):
          Console.WriteLine("Monday is second day")
          break;
       etc...
    }
```

Comment: `case(2):` should read `"Monday is the second day"`; sorry, bitten by copy/paste.

Comment: 1. You missed the semicolons on the WriteLines, 2. I'm pretty sure you don't require brackets on the case 1. But anyways, good job :D

Comment: Correct, you don't need the brackets around `(1)` it's just a habit I have to help my readability; I like to section out/contain my comparison object.  The missed semi-colons were exactly that, missed - sorry :)